# MySQL table - calculate points for last 12 months

Tags: mysql

I have a user community where user can get "userpoints" for specific actions like writing a comment (+5 points), uploading an image (+10 points), etc. The points get be used to "buy" things like a t-shirt (-100 points). Every action is logged to the MySQL table `userpoints_log`:

- id (int, PK)
- user_id (int, FK to user table)
- action_id (int, FK to action table)
- points (int, the points itself like +5 or -100)
- created_at (date)

Currently, I calculate the userpoints for each user, just by making a `SUM()` of all point logs in this table (identified by the user_id):

```
SELECT SUM(points) AS 'result' FROM userpoints_log 
WHERE user_id = X
GROUP BY user_id
```

Now I need to change this calculation, because all (positive) points should be only valid for 12 months. First I thougt, I just do the following:

```
SELECT SUM(points) AS 'result' FROM userpoints_log 
WHERE user_id = X AND created_at > DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY user_id
```

But that gives me some wrong results. For example, for the following dataset:

```
created_at |points
------------------
2016-04-01   | +1000
2016-05-01   |  -500
2016-06-01   |  +500
```

If I would run the query above on the 2017-04-15, I would get as result 0 points (-500+500), which isn't correct, since the user should have 500 points.

500 points is the correct result, because when a user use his points (-500) he uses his "oldest" points first and he can't use future points. If we assume, that we exclude the +1000 points from 2016-04-01, then 500 of them are already used (-500 on 2016-05-01).

Any ideas which formula or query I can use, to get the correct values?

Comment: Did you try to look at `GROUP BY`close?
I think you miss something like a `GROUP BY user_id` or whatever you want group on

Comment: Can you provide some details on why your desired output in that example is 500, instead of 0?

Comment: @IkeWalker: Updated the question. To sum up: 500 points is the correct result, because when a user use his points (-500) he uses his "oldest" points first and he can't use future points. If we assume, that we exclude the +1000 points from 2016-04-01, then 500 of them are already used (-500 on 2016-05-01).

Comment: @ShikatsuKagaminara: you are right, I missed the 'group by' but only in my example here, not in my real code

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(case when points < 0 and create_at < (
  select min(create_at) from userpoints_log where user_id = X
  and created_at > DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR) and points > 0
) then 0 else points) AS 'result' 
FROM userpoints_log 
WHERE user_id = X AND created_at > DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

that is psedo code but you can use that logic.
1. find first + point date
2. change - point data before first earned